# TFS Build Failure - Unable to find Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

After updating to TFS 2017 Update 2 RC1, my builds are failing because Visual Studio 2017 (MSBuild 15.0) is not found. I am using the 'Visual Studio Build' task with 'Latest' selected as the Visual Studio version.

- I have reinstalled Visual Studio Build Tools 2017.
- I have repaired my TFS installation.
- I have reinstalled my Build Agent.
- I have verified that my Build Agent has Visual Studio 2017 and MSBuild 15.0
  capabilities.

The only way I am able to get a successful build is to replace my 'Visual Studio Build' tasks with 'MSBuild', and manually direct to the MSBuild executable. I don't find this acceptable, I have too many Build configurations that would need to be changed. And when the next version of MSBuild comes out, I have to manually update them all.

Build Agent Capabilities:
[MSBuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiFMj.png)
[Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2sLM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you directly select **VS2017** instead of latest in the *VS version* option, then trigger the build again.
[image]

To narrow down the issue, you could try below ways:

- Create a new build definition with the same settings to build the
  project
- Use the build definition to build another Visual Studio 2017 project such as a new created one
- Enable TFS Build debug logging by adding a variable named
  ***system.debug*** and setting its value to '**true**'. This will enable full debug logging to correct more info.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. See the pastebin link to the section of the log relating to obtaining the Visual Studio path. https://pastebin.com/JR97HNCz

Comment: @AndrewJohnson According to the log, it seems the build service account could not find the VS path. One thing I can think of, if the agent is running as a service account, does the service account have access to the VS installation directory? Please double check this. And did you update your build agent after TFS update? Try to use the latest version of the build agent from GitHub (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases) and try it again.

Comment: Since the MSBuild task (pointed directly to the MSBuild path in Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\...) works fine, that tells me that the build agent has access to that path. Also, I did update my build agent from github yesterday before I submitted the question. Thanks again for the suggestions, but so far I have checked these items and still no luck.